# How do I scrape data from Trip Advisor by using Selenium? - Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am learning how to use selenium to scrape data from TripAdvisor via Python, and would like to extract the information of hotels after being sorted by "Traveler Ranked" in the link of (https://en.tripadvisor.com.hk/Hotels-g294217-Hong_Kong-Hotels.html).  **Name of hotels and the "data-location=" of each hotel** in the html page would like to be extracted.

[The html code of "data-location="][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x668S.png

Here is my code. I don't know why it cannot print the hotel name. I also don't know how to list out the number inside the "data-location=".

```
!pip install selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://en.tripadvisor.com.hk/Hotels-g294217-Hong_Kong-Hotels.html')

browser.maximize_window()
CheckinDate = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]')
CheckinDate.click()

CheckOutDate = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]')
CheckOutDate.click()

Roombutton = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/button')
Roombutton.click()

WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="component_15"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/div/div'))).click()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="component_15"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div').click()

results = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#bodycon_main .prw_meta_hsx_responsive_listing')
for result in results:
    try:
        link = result.find_element_by_xpath("./div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/a")
        print(link.text)
    except:
        continue
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not locating the `results` variable correctly, which returned an empty object, leading to no output. The following code should work.

Code Snippet-

```
CheckinDate = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]')
CheckinDate.click()

CheckOutDate = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]')
CheckOutDate.click()

Roombutton = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/button')
Roombutton.click()

WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="component_15"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/div/div'))).click()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="component_15"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div').click()

#time sleep to wait for all results to load after applying the preferences
#can be adjusted accordingly
time.sleep(10)

#locate all hotel results
results = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="prw_rup prw_meta_hsx_responsive_listing ui_section listItem"]')

#for each hotel in page results
for result in results:
    try:
        #find hotel name
        link = result.find_element_by_xpath('*//div[@class="listing_title"]/a')

        #find class which contains data-location attribute
        data_location=result.find_element_by_xpath('*//div[@class="pdWrapper node-preserve ajax_preserve"]').get_attribute("data-location")
        
        print(link.text)
        print(data_location)

    except:
        continue
```

Comment: It works. Thanks so much!